# Why did the initial victim change so slowly?

Tags: midnight-mass-2021

At the beginning of the series, we saw that

> Monsignor Pruitt walked around

during the day without any trouble.
It was days, at the very least, if not weeks, before Pruitt's condition progressed to the point that he could no longer tolerate sunlight, and he did not exhibit as much loss of control as most of the others.

However, Riley exhibited extreme sensitivity to sunlight mere hours after drinking the blood of the winged vampire. Similarly, the townsfolk who were transformed in the final episode turned to ash upon daybreak.

As such, why did Pruitt change so slowly?

Answer (score 4):

Drinking small amounts of the vampire’s blood only rejuvenated and reversed bodily damage/diseases.  For the full transformation to occur, the victim needs to die first which we later see when the priest falls off dead with obvious signs of ingesting poison and then coming back to life. It’s only after this point he develops his photosensitivity.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the priest (Pruitt) died when he was attacked by the vampire in Israel, and then was brought back with its blood (not by a small amount, either), but he first exhibited vulnerability to sunlight after he accidentally killed the fisherman. Are you thinking of another person?

Comment: He didn’t seem to die when he was attacked. He lost a lot of blood, sure, but I don’t remember getting the impression he died in the cave.  We definitely see him die later and exhibit the same poisoning signs as Pike (the dog)

Comment: You are referring to when he fell over and came back? My impression was that that was a side effect from his vampirization, and possibly from being out in the sun (when it might have had a more mild effect). He was also falling over in the church, for instance. And what reason would he have to drink poison right then?

Comment: After going back and looking over it, yes, his sensitivity to sunlight did appear directly after he fell over and came back. I attributed that to side effects of the vampirization (since he was the only one that we had seen up until that point), but it *is* more consistent with him having committed suicide by drinking poison. His earlier stumbles could have been due to his having taken a smaller dose, so it took longer to work. Why *would* he poison himself, though? How did he know that it would complete his transformation?

Comment: And yet, if his fainting in the church was because of the poison, why did he take a dose that took so long to kill him? Why did try to pass it off as a dizzy spell? Perhaps he meant to take enough to kill him, but he didn't, so he drank a larger does later?

Comment: @Adamant sounds like that could be a followup question!

Comment: There is a short scene showing Bev put poison back on the shelf, indicating to the viewer she had used it again.